# Convert Javascript String Array to C++ String Array

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I'm currently working on node addon, is there an easy way to convert string array parameter from node and use it to c++ like a simple c++ array? I am not that knowledgeable in v8. I just wanna use node addon for my modules to gain more speed.

what I tried is:

```
//this wont work
void getArray(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args){
     Isolate * isolate = args.GetIsolate();

     string c_array = args[0];

     for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
         //iterate c_array here
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this node-addon-api or napi or nan?

Comment: node-addon-api @Root0x

Comment: Assuming that the javascript array is a string you can use the c++ header only library called rapidjson. This allows you to parse the string into an array and it gives you a relatively simple way to interact with the array. I know its not the solution you were looking for but in my time with native admins this was the only way i found.